# C# assigning values for textboxes with names as series using for loop

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have text boxes with names as follows:

txt1
txt2
...
txtn

How do I assign values to these text boxes using a for loop?

```
for (1 to n)
{
   txt(i) = value1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you use so meaningless names at all? If you have so many `TextBoxes` you should consider to use a different control like `DataGridView` or show less controls on one form.

However, if all of these `TextBoxes` are on the same container control (like a `Panel`) you can use `Enumerable.OfType` to find all of them:

```
foreach(TextBox txt in txtPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    // ...
}
```

Another approach is using [`Controls.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(`true` means recursive):

```
TextBox txt = this.Controls.Find("txt1", true).Cast<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
```